# flip a 2d array

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to get a 2D array to a form, so I can work with it like I need. I just cant modify it correctly..

Say I have a 2D array:

```
0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 3 0 
0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I flip it to its symmetrical, so at the moment position 0,1 is 1 and therefore position 1,0 would be 1?

does this make seance?

I need to do this so I can work out Euler tour

Comment: This is too homework-y to have us help with, at least until you try it yourself and show us what you've done so far.

Comment: you need a generic algorithm in a meta-language or is this a language specific question? if the latter, which language?

Answer (score 1):

You could just access it in a flipped way.

```
x = 3;
y = 5;

// Ask for x,y element
$normal = $myarray[$x][$y];         

// Ask for x,y in the flipped array by asking for y,x
$flipped_access = $myarray[$y][$x];
```

Comment: i need a fully symmetircal matrix, this is the problem here, otherwise i would definatley use this solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (pseudo code)?

```
for x = 0 to width
  for y = 0 to x-1
     swap( array[x][y], array[y][x] )
```

Although depending on what your environment is, there might be special methods to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it same as transposing a square matrix?

```
(for i=0; i < order; i++) {
  for(j =i; j < order; j++) {
   temp = arr[i][j];
   arr[i][j] = arr[j][i];
   arr[j][i] = temp;
 }
}
```